# Mysterious Wi-Fi Direct Broadcasts

Tags: windows, wifi

At my company, or networking and info sec teams noticed mysterious Wi-Fi Direct broadcasts on our network from our corporate laptops. I'm currently looking into this issue to figure out what's causing them and how to shut them off.

It appears that this may be caused by Windows 10's "Project to this PC" feature, since this looks to be the only Win10 feature to use Wi-Fi Direct (please correct me if I'm wrong!). Since I can't remote into these machines during work hours to verify, I wrote a PowerShell script to check the registry keys.  The result looks similar to this:

| Name | Verison | WiFiDirectService | WiFiDirectAdapterStatus | NetworkQualificationEnabled | ConsentToast | AutoEnabled | SharedExperiences (Key: EnableCdp) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Device 1 | 1909 | Stopped | Up | 0 | 2 | 1 | Value does not exist |
| Device 2 | 2004 | Stopped |  | Value does not exist | Value does not exist | Value does not exist | Value does not exist |
| Device 3 | 1909 | Stopped | Up | 0 | 2 | 1 | Value does not exist |
| Device 4 | 1909 | Stopped |  | 1 | 2 | 1 | Value does not exist |
| Device 5 | 2004 | Stopped |  | Value does not exist | Value does not exist | Value does not exist | Value does not exist |
| Device 6 | 2004 | Stopped |  | Value does not exist | Value does not exist | Value does not exist | Value does not exist |
| Device 7 | 2004 | Stopped |  | Value does not exist | 2 | Value does not exist | Value does not exist |
| Device 8 | 1909 | Stopped |  | Value does not exist | Value does not exist | Value does not exist | Value does not exist |
| Device 9 | 2004 | Stopped |  | Value does not exist | Value does not exist | Value does not exist | Value does not exist |
| Device 10 | 1909 | Stopped |  | Value does not exist | Value does not exist | Value does not exist | Value does not exist |
| Device 11 | 1909 | Stopped |  | Value does not exist | Value does not exist | Value does not exist | Value does not exist |
| Device 12 | 2004 | Stopped |  | 1 | 2 | 1 | Value does not exist |
|  |  |  |  | 0 = Always Off/Available everywhere | 1 = First time only | 0 = Always Off |  |
|  |  |  |  | 1 = Available everywhere on secure networks | 2 = Every time a connection is requested | 1 = Available everywhere/Available everywhere on secure networks |  |
|  |  |  |  | "Some Windows and Android devices can project to this PC when you say it's ok" | "Ask to project to this PC" |  |  |

I've also found these pages that explain the keys a bit:

1. https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/49083-turn-off-projecting-pc-windows-10-a.html
2. https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/49088-change-when-ask-project-pc-windows-10-a.html

My understanding via testing is that changing "AutoEnabled" to 1 will enable the feature and changing "NetworkQualificationEnabled" controls if it's available everywhere or only on secure networks. Running a Wireshark trace on the Wi-Fi Direct adapter confirms that traffic/broadcasts stop when the feature is disabled.

What I find **very** interesting is that for some devices, the keys do not exist at all and I have not been able to find anything online regarding this. Why would these devices be appearing with Wi-Fi Direct broadcasts when the registry keys to control the Project to this PC feature do not exist?

This led me to look into the Shared Experiences feature (included in my audit) and for that the "EnableCdp" key just needs to not exist for it to be enabled. However, running a Wireshark trace during a large file transfer showed that the traffic was going over the normal Wi-Fi adapter and not the adapter for Wi-Fi Direct. This leads me to believe that this is not related to the issue we're experiencing.

Does anyone have any experience with this that can help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Cross-post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66748891/7233423 and https://superuser.com/q/1635289/669855